# xcode 8 beta Alamofire compiler errors after pod update to 3.4.1

Tags: xcode, swift, alamofire

I have downloaded a legacy swift app using git and run `pod update`. After `git add -A`, I open the workspace using xcode 8 beta then Product -> Clean and build I get 40 swift compiler Alamofire errors. I have not run convert o swift 2.3 or swift 3.

Podfile.lock has version 3.4.1 for Alamofire.

in Podfile I set the version to ios 10.0 and in Alamofire info also set infoDictionary version to 10.0 but it made no difference.

Mostly they are syntax errors like NSURL needs to be renamed URL, etc.

I can't find any answers to this problem with Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 8 compiles against the iOS 10 SDK. This differs slightly from the iOS 9 SDK and thus the errors. You won't be able to use Xcode 8 with Swift 2.2 code.

If you look at the Alamofire branches, https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/branches, you'll see work on 2.3 and 3.0 compatibility.

Also, read this thread for details on how to use those branches: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1312.

Comment: What version of xcode can I use to compile Alamofire 3.4.1?

Comment: Xcode 7.x should work. For Xcode 8, you should use the branches `swift2.3` or `swift3`

Comment: Thanks, I'll test xcode 7 and then accept your answer if it works.

Comment: I used the following entry in my Podfile to install Alamofire for swift 2.3, What was provided in above link did not work.


 `pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => ‘swift2.3'`

Comment: to avoid [!] Your Podfile has had smart quotes sanitised.  from @nmvictor answer fix last smart quote: 'swift2.3'

Comment: For me finally I used Alamofire 3.5.0  with Xcode 8 / Swift 2.3

Comment: Hi @someone0 did you added this in your podFile to get the 3.5.0 version? pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0' ? Still this working for you?

Comment: @Llg I use exactly the 3.5.0 version and it's working, with the following line:      pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.5.0'